# Selection sort count number of swaps

Tags: sorting

http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/animations/Sort1.html is this applet counting right? Selection sort for 5 4 3 2 1, I see 2 swaps, but the applet is counting 4 exchanges....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a matter of definition. He is doing a swap in the end of every loop, even if he is swapping one element against itself. In his case, the swaps will be:

- Original:          5 4 3 2 1
- Swap pos 1 and 5:  1 4 3 2 5
- Swap pos 2 and 4:  1 2 3 4 5
- Swap pos 3 and 3:  1 2 3 4 5
- Swap pos 4 and 4:  1 2 3 4 5

(No swap is done for the last element since that will always be in the correct place)

A simple if statement could be used to eliminate the two last swaps.

Comment: - 5 4 3 2 1 (initial state)
- 1 4 3 2 5 (swapped 5 and 1)
- 1 2 3 4 5 (swapped 4 and 2)

Comment: Yep, I agree. No use swapping an element against itself.